# How to speed up concurrent identical queries SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-performance

I've inherited a solution to support based on .NET and SQL Server 2008 R2.

The architecture is such that all clients must be kept in step with each other, and this is handled by a winsock hub to which each client sends and receives notifications of changes made. These notifications are in the form of a type of update and a key field.

On receipt of a notification, client windows inspect the type of update and if they think they are interested then issue a database command (Stored procedure) to retrieve the latest data for that key value. The stored procedure typically invoked links a number of tables to return a rather large object.

My problem is that when many clients are active, they are calling the same stored procedure at the 'same' time and dragging perforamnce down e.g. a < 1 second query, when called in isolation can take c20 seconds as it presumably waits for other clients to complete.

Is there anything out of the box in SQL server that can help me with this?  I'm thinking of caching of results or ways in which I can stop one query blocking another?

I appreciate that I should probably make some changes on the client code and notification process to pass around fully populated objects so removing the need to interrogate the database multiple times. However this is a legacy application with a limited lifespan, which would be a headache to upgrade in such a significant way. If there were a nice simple switch in SQL server I could use, that would buy me the time I need!

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: First, seems you are having blocking issues and some of them can be solved quickly. If you are blocking tables to wait for a result, but the stored procedure doesn't modify tables, then try to use WITH (NOLOCK) in every table. You know changes ongoing are not going to be selected but many times is a simple workaround. Second, it could be better you post your query, might be there's a problem and you didn't see it, it becomes obvious when there're more people querying your data. Third, a profiler will well you to see if you're right the blocking is the main problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd already tried (NOLOCK) but it didn't help.  I would post the SP but it is huge (maybe part of my problem!).  One thing I realised when I just reviewed my use of NOLOCK is that I use a #temporary table in the sp.  Any thoughts on what impact this could have in terms of blocking?

Comment: Temporary tables are very tricky and it depends on your context. Remember they are stored in the tempdb. High use of temp tables requires a different schema, in fact I saw a couple of times systems using temp tables located in flashcards to optimize them to the maximum. But temp tables don't cause blocking unless they're global temp tables. Another guess is your tempdb is having a performance issue and it's slow to build the table, but it would be a very particular situation.

Comment: Do something quick, open a profiler to trace your SP only, start it and check what is going on, you must see big delays somewhere.

Comment: One more, during normal execution of your query, I mean when users are working and it's slow, try to query the database locking for the block. In case there's one or more than one you will find it, it could be blocking is not your problem, might be it's a slow performance somewhere (tempdb?) when many users are accessing your database. Try this:

Comment: select  
    object_name(P.object_id) as TableName, 
    resource_type, resource_description
from
    sys.dm_tran_locks L
    join sys.partitions P on L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id

Answer (score 0):

Tips to keep in mind:

- First, add WITH (NOLOCK) to tables where you can do it. Remember NOLOCK is a hint for READUNCOMMITED which means it won't read pending changes already in process but it will prevent to wait until a table is released
- Use sp_who2 while investigating in production server. Launch your application or website in more than one machine in order to reproduce the scenario that causes a slower performance, get reports or operations that takes time and analyze what's going on in a Management Studio with sp_who2. You will be able to identify SUSPENDED selects
- Use sp_lock to see which objects exactly are locked

Locked types can be:

- MD - metadata lock
- DB - database lock
- TAB - table lock
- PAG - page lock

If nothing works you can try analyzing query plans but you indicated performance is good when you are in an isolated environment and query this procedure.

Another performance issue, your tempdb database can be overloaded by temporary tables if it's not optimized. Run a profiler to analyze what's happening. Filter only the stored procedure you need to evaluate results.

I will add more information in case something else comes up to my mind.

Comment: Thanks Maximiliano. Just waiting for a period of poor performance to try some of your suggestions. I find the stored procedure acquiring a lot of exclusive Extent locks - don't understand why or if this is relevant.

Comment: Have you checked indexes in the database? Many extent locks are typically related to that.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing help. What do you mean by check the indexes?

Comment: Table indexes, fragmentation, rebuild indexes, those typical tasks of maintenance. Many extent locks are normal when indexes are not working pretty well.

Comment: Could you make any progress with this? I hope so.